# Get POST variable that is an array

Tags: php

All,

I have the following hidden variables:

```
<input type="hidden" name="chk[10]" value = "cats">
<input type="hidden" name="chk[13]" value = "dogs">
<input type="hidden" name="chk[14]" value = "fish">
```

I want to get these variables through POST and print them. How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/types.array http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['chk'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' => ', $value, '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$chks = $_POST["chk"];
print_r($chks);
```