# how to pass row id to query single row in php/msql

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

i have a problem querying my mysql table to fetch a single row so that i can print it using fpdf library. So far, i can query and print the entire table, but i can't print it dynamically based on the row id. Here is datatable setup;

```
<tr>
                        <td>'.$data["cardId"].'</td>
                        <td id="surname_'.$data["cardId"].'">'.$data["surname"].', '.$data["givenName"].'</td>
                        <td id="resAddress_'.$data["cardId"].'">'.$data["resAddress"].'</td>
                        <td id="resSuburb_'.$data["cardId"].'">'.$data["resSuburb"].'</td>
                        <td id="jobTitle_'.$data["cardId"].'">'.$data["jobTitle"].'</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" onclick="viewORedit('.$data["cardId"].', \'edit\')" value="Edit / View" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <form method="get" action="invoice.php">
                            <input type="submit" value="Generate" name='.$data["cardId"].' class="btn btn-success">
                            </form>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <input type="button" onclick="deleteRow('.$data["cardId"].')" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

i'm using the Generate button to pull and generate the data. here is my SQL query and pdf setup;

```
$pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');


$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(50,50,100);

$id = '.$data["cardId"].';
$query=mysqli_query($connection,

               "SELECT 
                    surname, otherSurname, givenName, jobTitle
                FROM 
                    cards, employment
                WHERE 
                    cards.cardId = '$id'");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['surname'], 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['otherSurname'], 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['givenName'], 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['jobTitle'], 1, 1);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

If i delete passing the id, i get all records printed in the pdf. If i add the id, i get no results(Only the pdf formatting). But i want to get the row id so i can generate a pdf of that row's data instead of printing the entire table. Please help.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with this line `$id = '.$data["cardId"].';` Can you do `echo $id` under that line to see if the variable contains anything?

Comment: That is correct. I'm not passing the correct row id from the datatable. Any ideas on how to pass the correct row id when i click the Generate button? This is the response i get when i `echo $id` -- `.$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"]..$data["cardId"].`

Comment: That should be `$id = $data['cardId']`. As it is now, you're setting `$id` to a static string. Don't forget to sanitise the input to avoid SQL injection, never trust data from the user. Appending unchecked data to a query is dangerous in a public system. Consider using PDO or prepared SQL statements.

Comment: Cool! You are right ! Although i tried `$id = $data['cardId']` but i get an undefined variable error now. Thanks bro i will do that, just working on a POC for now, i'm a bit new to PHP lol

Comment: @Rayzor536 You are getting undefined variable because `$data[ 'cardID' ]` does not exists. The variable is not declared in that file. You need to POST the variable from the HTML page and set the $id varible using the POST reference. See this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990990/get-post-variable-that-is-an-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks! @IbrahimHafiji. Will try this now! Thanks guys

Comment: I tried passing the POST reference but i'm getting an undefined key error. Is there any easier method to pass the row id so i can query a single row :(

Answer (score 0):

If id is an int in the db and you use single quotes('') it will return an error ints do not need the quotes.  You can try something like this.

```
"SELECT surname, otherSurname, givenName, jobTitle
FROM cards, employment
WHERE cards.cardId = ".$id."");
```

This $data["cardId"] var needs to be in php tags and echo back like this.

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="<?php echo $data["cardId"];?>" class="btn btn-success">
```

Comment: Hi @Jonny, yes.. id is an int.. I have it wrapped in the table as cardId.. I need to know how to pass cardId from my db to my query from the datatable like you mentioned above.

Comment: can you post the complete form and the php that gets $data["cardId"]?

Comment: yes sure. This is my ajax.php file where my datatable is loaded dynamically - the 'getExistingData' key is called via ajax from a different page(that works fine). Also, my "view/edit" and "delete" buttons work fine. Only the "Generate" button doesn't pass the id to the invoice.php file.. (https://pastebin.com/QWDXkb9Z). And this is my php file where i'm trying to print the data in a pdf (https://pastebin.com/dvxv9mwe)

Comment: Try the above you may have to echo the var